# Which SE site is appropriate for code formatting questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where should we ask questions about how code should be formatted, which are primarily opinion-based?

These would be questions like "How do you format your nested if-statements?"

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ maybe appropriate if you just want people review your code

Answer (score 9):

> Where should we ask questions about how code should be formatted, **which are primarily opinion-based**?

emphasis added

Nowhere, simply because they are primarily opinion based.

Agree on a standard - any standard - within your team and stick to it.

Comment: What if I am my own team? I'd like to see how other people do it.

Comment: @Aaroninus ask in a chat room - either here on SO or on some other forum

Comment: Also browse the tag of your choice for a bit, and you will see what the established users prefer (as well as what the askers happen to give). Another way is looking at the sources for some projects you like.

Comment: @Aaroninus: Then read questions and answers here tagged with the language you're using, and see how other people do it, and decide which is easiest for you to read and understand (and maintain when you go back to it 6 months from now).

Comment: +1 @Aaroninus - "if I am my own team" - if you can't agree with yourself on coding standard for your code... I don't even know if any SO sites can help with that problem... As an option - pick a company you like and use its coding standards.